# Index class as list and as dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is it good practice to give a class behavior both of a `list` and a `dict`? 
This allows one to access items via both: `instance[str]` and `instance[int]`.
For example:

```
class Population(object):
    def __init__(self, populationlist):
        self.population = populationlist

    def __getitem__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            index = self.get_names().index(value)
            return self.population[ index ]
        elif isinstance(value, int:
            return self.population[value]

    def get_names(self):
        return [ ind.name for ind in self.population ]

class Individual(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

my_pop = Population( [ Individual(name) for name in [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] ] )

my_pop['c']
>> 'c'
my_pop[2]
>> 'c'
```

Comment: `if type(value) is str` is more pythonic.

Comment: and what should happen if your `self.population` contains integers?

Comment: This can be misleading. When someone sees `my_pop['c']` he might think that `my_pp` is a dict, but it's not really a one.

Comment: is `self.population[ self.population.index(value) ]` not equal to `value`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the really Pythonic thing to do is `if isinstance(value, str)`.

Comment: I edited to 'isinstance(value, str). @Arman: This is an example, I intend to have the populationlist being a list of instances of an Individual class. Such that it returns a class instance, not just the value.

Comment: What is the string key? The value itself? Then can't you just do that instead of querying? I'd say permitting this type of operation is redundant and confusing

Comment: @Fallen (and Arman) Not if there are several duplicates of the same "item". `index` returns the index of the first occurrence.

Comment: I don't get the purpose of the list emulation. If there is no existing strong relation to an integer index, this is just an additional and somewhat inferior way for iterating through all elements. Take a look to iteritems/iterkeys methods (python 2.7) or items and keys (python 3) of dictionary instead.

Comment: This code and its purpose makes little sense to me to begin with. What is the bigger plan here?

Comment: @MSeifert Could you please add an example?

Comment: This could become quite confusing - if, for example, the initial population was `['6', '8', '4', '2']` then `my_pop[2] = '4'` but `my_pop['2'] = '2'`

Comment: @Fallen That's a more hypothetical case but `index` uses `==` to look for the item. If you have a class that compares equal for slightly different instances then you might get a different item than the one you requested. I.e. if you mix data types. Try `lst = ['a', 1, 1.0]; lst[lst.index(1.0)]`. That **doesn't** return `1.0`!

Comment: @asongtoruin `my_pop['2'] = 2` <- this should not happen; there is no `'2'` in the list

Comment: @Ev.Kounis my mistake - corrected the comment

Comment: I still think it's not a valid reason to add this ambiguity. From the examples, it's clear that if you request with a string, the string itself is returned. So the OP should actually check it's presence instead of checking this way for string keys.

Comment: What does `return self.population[ self.population.index(value) ]` even do? Just check if `value` is in the list?

Comment: I have another question. Is this an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `if isinstance(value, str)` isn't the same thing. It checks the class and the children too (works for inherited types of `str`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask if it's **good practice** and the answer is a clear: **No**.

There are some good practices mentioned in the Python module `this`:

```
>>> import this
```

There are four lines that somewhat apply here:

- `Explicit is better than implicit.`:

  You implicitly convert a string index to a numeric index!
- `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.`

  This is clearly a special case when you enter a string index. What makes it special?
- `In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.`

  That's almost like the special case point. You're guessing that noone would enter an equivalent second item (return the first or second or last then?) and noone would use integers as names.
- `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`

  I think this one is quite subjective but I interpret this as "one function should have **one** purpose that no other function fulfills". Your `__getitem__` has two purposes. It wouldn't be a problem to have a method `"find_by_name"` and one method `"find_by_index"`.

---

However to also include some constructive feedback: It almost looks like you want a tabular structure. If so you should consider [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) or some database, maybe `sqllite`?

Just to show how `pandas` solved this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
>>> print(df)
  name
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d


>>> print(df[df['name'] == 'a'])  # index by name
  name
0    a

>>> print(df.iloc[[0]])           # index by index
  name
0    a
```

Comment: Although knowing [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is important it was written specifically as a guideline for Python design, not software made with Python. The OP case study does not seem particularly interesting to me but Python flexibility towards allowing different idiomatic approaches  are one of the most powerful features any software architect could ask for. That being said there are plenty of cases where doing this kind of "object customization" can be extremely beneficial.

Comment: @armatita well, it's a guideline, not a set of rules. But the OP specially asked about "good practice" and then such things become important. Also I explained in each point why I thought it wouldn't be good. It's not that I just quoted the Zen.

Comment: Oh! I wasn't judging. As I said the case study of the OP does not sound very useful to me but I can imagine situations where a customized Idiom can greatly improve development speed and quality. For example the [slice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=slice%20object#slice) notation is a clear attempt at making a preferential query(ish) style to container objects, with [great success](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) but also very set apart from the common Python syntax. If it helps you, go for it!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you **can** create a class that handles all of this for you **but** it **won't be optimized**. What you should do is use Python's `OrderedDict` to have an efficient dictionary that has an order.